# I could send the emails in magento for those city is same?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created a criteria as when the islab is checked and the location and zip code is matches then it has to send the mails.But I can send the emails when the islab is checked but not when the city and zipcode matches.Please anyone can help me.

as When it is applicable it has send the emails to providers.Ex:if islab=1,city="XXXXXXX"and zipcode="XXXXX"

In my code at service provider code I added but it not working.

```
   <?php
   $uploadfilename="";
      if( !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])  and  $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
    { 

        $image_ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        $allowed_ext =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg','jpeg','pdf','doc','docx','rtf','odt');

        $uploadfilename = md5(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,100).rand(1,100))).str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); 
         $source_upl         = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_path_upl = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename;  
        if(in_array($image_ext ,$allowed_ext ) ) {
            @move_uploaded_file($source_upl, $target_path_upl);
        }
    }
  function sendMailAction($uploadfilename){
   //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
    $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];



      if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab'){
      $name=$_POST['name'];
        $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
      $testname=$_POST['testname'];
      $email=$_POST['labemail'];
         $mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
       $city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
     $html=
    '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
   <p>Testname: '.$testname.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
    <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
       <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>
    ';
      }
        else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
      {


 $name=$_POST['pname'];
 $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
 $email=$_POST['pemail'];
 $city=$_POST['pcity'];
 $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
    $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
 $html=
'<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
<p>Medicinename: '.$medicine.'</p>
<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
 <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
 <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

 }
 else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
  {
 $name=$_POST['fname'];
 $email=$_POST['femail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
 $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
 $html=
'<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
<p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
<p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
 }

  else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
  {
 $name=$_POST['fname'];
 $email=$_POST['femail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
  $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
 $html=
 $html=
  '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
<p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
<p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
<p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
 }
    else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
  {
 $name=$_POST['fname'];
 $email=$_POST['femail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
  $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
  $html=
  $html=
  '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
  <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
  <p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
  <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
   <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
   <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
   }
   else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
 {
 $name=$_POST['fname'];
 $email=$_POST['femail'];
 $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
    $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
 $html=
  $html=
  '<p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
  <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
<p>Email:'.$email.'</p>
<p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
<p>City:'.$city.'</p>
 <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
 }



    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


    $mail->addTo('admin@labwise.in',$name);

    $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
    $mail->setBodyHtml($html);
      if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
   {

       $attachment =  file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
   $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
   $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
    $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
  $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
   $mail->addAttachment($file);
    }



    try {
       $mail->send();

    //return '<h2> Email Sent.   </h2>';

       }
     catch (Exception $e) {

        //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 

     }

        }

     //Customer mail
      function sendMailcustomerAction(){
   //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

   if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab'){
     $name=$_POST['name'];
   $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
   $email=$_POST['labemail'];
    $testname=$_POST['testname'];
     $html=

  'Dear '.$name.',

      <p>We have received your order for '.$testname.'. You will be  attended shortly.</p>

    <p>Best Regards,</p>
     <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
   }
   else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
   { $name=$_POST['pname'];
    $email=$_POST['pemail'];
     $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
   $html=

    'Dear '.$name.',

      <p>We have received your order for '.$medicine.'. You will be attended shortly.</p>

     <p>Best Regards,</p>
     <p>Team Labwise.</p>';

     }

      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
        {
         $name=$_POST['fname'];
         $email=$_POST['femail'];
          $html=
      'Dear '.$name.',

       <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

      <p>Best Regards,</p>
       <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
         }
        else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
       {
           $name=$_POST['fname'];
         $email=$_POST['femail'];
          $html=
      'Dear '.$name.',

      <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

       <p>Best Regards,</p>
       <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
        }
      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
      {
         $name=$_POST['fname'];
         $email=$_POST['femail'];
        $html=
      'Dear '.$name.',

        <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

       <p>Best Regards,</p>
         <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
         }
        else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
       {
          $name=$_POST['fname'];
        $email=$_POST['femail'];
         $html=
       'Dear '.$name.',

       <p>We have received your order. You will be attended shortly.</p>

         <p>Best Regards,</p>
        <p>Team Labwise.</p>';
        }

       $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName($name);
     $mail->setToEmail($email);
    $mail->setBody($html);
    $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
     $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
      $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
    //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
     $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

        try {
           $mail->send();
          //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
   return '<h2>Your Request has been submitted.Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
      //$this->_redirect('');
          }
    catch (Exception $e) {
 //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
   return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
 //$this->_redirect('');
    }
    }
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
 if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
 {
$allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.islab=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
 } else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
 {

  $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.ishospital=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
 {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isgym=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
 }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
  {
     $allrecord  =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isfood=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
   }
     /*else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
  {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isnurse=?', '1'
  );
 }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
  {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isphysio=?', '1'
  );
   }*/
     if(isset($alldata)) {
 foreach($alldata as $data)
 {
      sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name'],$uploadfilename);
 }}

 function sendMailserviceAction($ccemail,$pname,$uploadfilename){
//Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

 //$location=$_POST['location'];
  $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
    $cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
  $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
    $cemail=$_POST['femail'];

    if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
  {
  $cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
    $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
       $testname=$_POST['testname'];
   $name=$_POST['name'];
  $mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
     $city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
        $html ='
       <p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Testname:'.$testname.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
       <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
   <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
       <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
    <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

      }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
    {
      $name=$_POST['pname'];
    $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
      $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
   $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
      $html ='<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p> <p> Medicine name:         '.$medicine.'</p>
    <p>Name:'.$name.'</p>
     <p> Email: '.$cemail.'</p>
     <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
   <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
      }
      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
   {
$name=$_POST['fname'];
  $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
    $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
 $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
$html ='
    <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
   <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
     <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
  <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
   <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
   <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
   }
    else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
   {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
       $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
      $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];

     $html ='
      <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
       <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
    <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
  }



  $mail = new Zend_Mail();
  $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


  $mail->addTo($ccemail,$pname);

  $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
  $mail->setBodyHtml($html); 
         if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {

     $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
   $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
   $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
   $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
   $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
   $mail->addAttachment($file);
   }



 $mail->send();
}

echo sendMailAction($uploadfilename);
echo sendMailcustomerAction();
//echo sendMailserviceAction();
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
 if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
 {
$allrecord = "SELECT * from  mg_serviceprovider WHERE islab='1' and pincode='$zipcode' or city='$city' ";$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
 } else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
 {

  $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.ishospital=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
  }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
 {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isgym=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
 }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
  {
     $allrecord  =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isfood=?', '1'
  );$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
   }
     /*else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Nurse')
  {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isnurse=?', '1'
  );
 }else  if($_POST['servicetype']=='Physio')
  {
   $allrecord =$readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isphysio=?', '1'
  );
   }*/
     if(isset($alldata)) {
 foreach($alldata as $data)
 {
      sendMailserviceAction($data['email'],$data['name'],$uploadfilename);
 }}

 function sendMailserviceAction($ccemail,$pname,$uploadfilename){
//Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

 //$location=$_POST['location'];
  $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
    $cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
  $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
    $cemail=$_POST['femail'];

    if($_POST['servicetype']=='Lab')
  {
  $cemail=$_POST['labemail'];
    $servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
       $testname=$_POST['testname'];
   $name=$_POST['name'];
  $mobile=$_POST['labmobile'];
     $city=$_POST['rcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['labzip_code'];
        $html ='
       <p>Service Type: '.$servicetype.'</p>
      <p>Testname:'.$testname.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
       <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
   <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
       <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
    <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';

      }else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
    {
      $name=$_POST['pname'];
    $medicine=$_POST['medicinename'];
      $cemail=$_POST['pemail'];
   $mobile=$_POST['pmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['pcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['pzip_code'];
      $html ='<p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p> <p> Medicine name:         '.$medicine.'</p>
    <p>Name:'.$name.'</p>
     <p> Email: '.$cemail.'</p>
     <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
   <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
     <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
      }
      else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Gym')
   {
$name=$_POST['fname'];
  $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
    $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
 $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];
$html ='
    <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
   <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
     <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
  <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
   <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
   <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
   }
    else if($_POST['servicetype']=='Food')
   {
     $name=$_POST['fname'];
       $cemail=$_POST['femail'];
      $mobile=$_POST['fmobile'];
      $city=$_POST['fcity'];$zipcode=$_POST['fzip_code'];

     $html ='
      <p>Service Type:'.$servicetype.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
      <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
       <p>Mobile number: '.$mobile.'</p>
    <p>City:'.$city.'</p>
    <p>Zip Code:'.$zipcode.'</p>';
  }



  $mail = new Zend_Mail();
  $mail->setFrom('admin@labwise.in',"Labwise");


  $mail->addTo($ccemail,$pname);

  $mail->setSubject('Quick Service');
  $mail->setBodyHtml($html); 
         if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename) and $_POST['servicetype']=='Pharmacy')
     {

     $attachment = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'requestquote'.DS.$uploadfilename);
   $ext = pathinfo($uploadfilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file = new Zend_Mime_Part($attachment);
   $file->filename    = $uploadfilename;
   $file->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
   $file->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
   $mail->addAttachment($file);
   }



 $mail->send();
}

echo sendMailAction($uploadfilename);
echo sendMailcustomerAction();
//echo sendMailserviceAction();
   ?>
```

Comment: The query you given is not working.It is not going to if block if zipcode fails.